# Laravel - Order by model

Tags: laravel, model

I am using Laravel 5.7 and I want to put at the end records that have empty data in the relationship table.

I have table Users and second table Packages which I am calling with $user->trainers_packages.

If the user doesn't have a package I want to put them at the very end.

This is my current code that doesn't sort.

```
public function treneri(){
  $treneri = User::where("status",1)->whereHas(
      'roles', function($q){
          $q->where('name', 'trener')->orWhere('name', 'nutricionista');;
      }
  )
  ->join('user_settings','users.id', '=', 'user_settings.user_id')
  ->whereNotNull("user_settings.opis")
  ->where("izlistan",1)
  ->with(["trainers_packages" => function($q){
    $q->orderBy('cena',"asc");
  }])
  ->orderBy('user_settings.verifikovan', 'desc')
  ->select('users.*')
  ->paginate(15);
  $ocekivanja = Iskustva::where("type","ocekivanja")->get();
  $vrsta = Iskustva::where("type","vrsta")->get();
  return view('treneri',compact('treneri','ocekivanja','vrsta'));
}
```

Comment: What about sorting by trainers_packages count as following:


->withCount('trainers_packages')->orderBy('trainers_packages_count', 'desc')

Comment: How can i sort by "trainers_packages_count" if that doesnt exists?

Comment: When including ->withCount('trainers_packages') in your query, laravel sets the count alias by default to {relation_name}_count.
Check the following link:


https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: Thats not the solution for laravel 5.7, i got error that column doesnt exists.

Comment: You want to sort records in ascending order, but the records which don't have values should be last? Or just sort them in descending order?

Comment: All users that doesn't have packages should be at the end.

Comment: I'm currently stuck on same sort of issue. As far as I have researched Laravel doesn't orderBy on child table column. You need to do a raw sql query. But, I can tell you of a Laravel package which does sorting on child table column. But, it would put NULL values at start. :(
Package:- https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join
Checkout orderByJoin method. Here is the trick now. I have Log::debug() SQL query that is being run with toSql() method. And I've modified that query to set NULL values at end. Now I have to execute the raw query inside the Laravel with DB::select()

Comment: @S.Farooq Am i able to use it in controller or just model? It won't work in controller, says orderByJoin doesnt exist ?

Comment: Have you used EloquentJoin trait on the model as it suggests in the documentation? If not, use EloquentJoin; on users model

Comment: After adding it on model you can use it on controller.

Comment: @S.Farooq yes i did, its working now. Didn't work after few refreshes. Thanks for sharing this link i will try something.